# DSFML building error (VisualD)

Tags: visual-studio, d, sfml

And at first, sorry for my bad English. It is my first project in D. And my first project with SFML (DSFML of course).

I use dub for making Visual Studio project (I use VS2010). Then
open it and set up project settings:

general
[image]

compiler
[image]

linker
[image]

Autocomplete works correctly:
[image]

When I try build project, here is error:

> Error 42: Symbol Undefined _D5dsfml8graphics12__ModuleInfoZ

How I can resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create project by `dub init dsfml_test` (where `dsfml_test` is our project name)
   [image: dub init_dsfml_test]
2. Add libs dependencies to `dub.json`
   [image: edit dub.json]
3. Generate Visual Studio project
   [image: dub generate visuald]
4. Open project in Visual Studio
   [image]
5. Open project properties
   [image: Project properties]
6. Enter path to directory where is placed dsfml lib files
   [image]

Thats all. Now can add `import dsfml.graphics, dsfml.window, dsfml.system;` ...etc and build project.

Answer (score 1):

This particular error is saying that it can't find the actual D code for the library. It could mean that dub isn't grabbing/linking the source somewhere, but I've never used dub with an IDE so I can't be sure.

My suggestion to help you figure out what is going wrong and to fix this issue is to bug the maintainer (who is me, actually) on github by opening an issue about a lack of tutorials for the IDE's that are available to D right now.

If you want to get started with DSFML right now, however, you can sort of follow along with the command line tutorial and use that as a basis of figuring out what libraries need to be linked in, set up import search paths, etc.

Comment: Thank you, Jebbs. DSFML is a great job. I now use it with Mono-D and it very like to me (but also I want use VisualD since here is debugger for D, and Xamarin 5 not have debugger for D). I will follow your advice, but little later (sorry, now I do not have time).

Comment: Hi, Jebbs. I understood, it works fine. It needed to generate the project (`dub generate visuald`) each time after adding dependencies in json. And then only add path to libs.